# Odometer on scroll position

Tags: scroll

Trying to trigger the setTimeout(function) to a scroll position of 850 but need some help....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var below_850 = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        below_850 = (top > 850);
    }

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer').html('652348');
  }, 1000);

   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar but when the user reaches that odometer element and not by a fixed scroll position. The following tutorial might help u:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/18/on-scroll-effect-layout/