# during scroll call a function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a counter on a page. When I scroll to it I need start it only once. but now it starts twice during next scroll. Thank's.

```js
var quit = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // ...
    something();

    function something() {
      if (quit == true) {
        return;
      }
      quit = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(begin).html(2002);
      }, 500); // this function must be call only once
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @OP, Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r48c4aft/ Above code is working fine..

Comment: sorry, but it's not working at start.

Comment: Is fiddle working ? If _NO_ then there is something else in your code which is not provided..

Comment: it wouldn't work in jsfiddle because it;s only a part of hole script,

Comment: your solution isn't work in my script, in jsfiddle-works

Comment: What does that mean ? Didn't I mentioned the same earlier comment ? Anyways, Did you see anything in console ? Any errors ?

Comment: I have a same trouble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882866/odometer-on-scroll-position

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    something();
        $(document).off('scroll');
});
```

Comment: `$(foo).one(...)`is designed for this

Answer (score 0):

this solution helped me https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/issues/35

my second mistake was creating "new odometer" object